# Fancybox doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, fancybox, fancybox-2

I've been through many topics on Fancybox problems with one or the other navigator. Though, I can't solve my problem on this page of my website http://www.lagrandemademoiselle.com/gite-ardeche.html .

It works very well on Google Chrome. But, either with fancybox 1 or fancybox 2, it doesn't work at all on my website when I am on Firefox. It only shows an image with a black background color, and without any "next" or "previous" or any other button.

Here is my code for the page with fancybox 1 (click on "L'INTERIEUR" or "LES CHAMBRES" on the menu of the website):

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        !window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"><\/script>');
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./galeries/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./galeries/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./galeries/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./galeries/fancybox/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("a[rel=mosaique]").fancybox({
                'titleShow'     : 'false',
                'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
                'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
                'titlePosition'     : 'over',
                'changeFade'        : 'slow',
            });
            $("#carte1").fancybox({
                'width'         : '85%',
                'height'        : '85%',
                'autoScale'     : false,
                'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
                'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
                'type'          : 'iframe'
            });
            $("#carte2").fancybox({
                'width'         : '85%',
                'height'        : '85%',
                'autoScale'     : false,
                'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
                'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
                'type'          : 'iframe'
            });
            $("#carte3").fancybox({
                'width'         : '85%',
                'height'        : '85%',
                'autoScale'     : false,
                'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
                'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
                'type'          : 'iframe'
            });
            $("#carte4").fancybox({
                'width'         : '85%',
                'height'        : '85%',
                'autoScale'     : false,
                'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
                'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
                'type'          : 'iframe'
            });
            $("#carte5").fancybox({
                'width'         : '85%',
                'height'        : '85%',
                'autoScale'     : false,
                'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
                'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
                'type'          : 'iframe'
            });    
        });
    </script>
```

And here is my code for the page where I tried to update to Fancybox 2 (click on "L'EXTERIEUR" on the menu of my website) :

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./fbv2/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./fbv2/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./fbv2/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./fbv2/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fbv2/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fbv2/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fbv2/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" />
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    nextClick : true,
        closeClick : true,
    helpers : { 
    overlay: {
        opacity: 0.8, // or the opacity you want 
        css: {'background-color': '#ff0000'} // or your preferred hex color value
     } // overlay 
    } // helpers
   }); // fancybox
    </script>
```

Comment: wrap your fancybox code in the `.ready()` method. check you old code as reference

Comment: Sorry for this error. But even if I fix it by copying and pasting  what is in the demo index.html of fancybox 2, it doesn't work (see code source on "L'EXTERIEUR" page). On the contrary, if I load the index.html of the demo folder on both navigators [link](http://www.lagrandemademoiselle.com/fbv2/demo/), it perfectly works on Mozilla and Chrome, with same code / script and the same files... What's wrong ? I've checked all paths and all scripts.

Comment: this [spip.php](http://www.lagrandemademoiselle.com/spip.php?page=jquery.js) module is loading a very old version of jQuery with many deprecated elements. That is creating some js errors that void your other scripts to work properly.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for the time spent on this case. I shall definitly upgrade SPIP to latest version.